# Fatal error: Class 'Response' not found

Tags: php, twitter, oauth, oauth-2.0, twitter-oauth

I'm working with Abraham's `twitteroauth` to implement Twitter OAuth in my application. While running my application, this is the error I'm encountering:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Response' not found in /opt/lampp/htdocs/tmhOAuth-master/twitteroauth.php on line 108
```

Now, this is what my `twitteroauth.php` file looks like till the 108th line:

```
<?php
/**
 * The most popular PHP library for use with the Twitter OAuth REST API.
 *
 * @license MIT
 */
//namespace twitteroauthm\src\TwitterOAuth;
//use twitteroauthm\src\TwitterOAuth;
use twitteroauthm\src\Util\JsonDecoder;

require "twitteroauthm/autoload.php";
use Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth as Config;
//require_once("twitteroauthm/src/TwitterOAuth.php");

//use twitteroauthm\src\TwitterOAuth;

//require_once("twitteroauthm/src/Config.php");

/**
 * TwitterOAuth class for interacting with the Twitter API.
 *
 * @author Abraham Williams <abraham@abrah.am>
 */
class TwitterOAuth extends Config
{
    const API_VERSION = '1.1';
    const API_HOST = 'https://api.twitter.com';
    const UPLOAD_HOST = 'https://upload.twitter.com';

    /** @var Response details about the result of the last request */
    private $response;
    /** @var string|null Application bearer token */
    private $bearer;
    /** @var Consumer Twitter application details */
    private $consumer;
    /** @var Token|null User access token details */
    private $token;
    /** @var HmacSha1 OAuth 1 signature type used by Twitter */
    private $signatureMethod;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param string      $consumerKey      The Application Consumer Key
     * @param string      $consumerSecret   The Application Consumer Secret
     * @param string|null $oauthToken       The Client Token (optional)
     * @param string|null $oauthTokenSecret The Client Token Secret (optional)
     */
    public function __construct($consumerKey, $consumerSecret, $oauthToken = null, $oauthTokenSecret = null)
    {
        $this->resetLastResponse();
        $this->signatureMethod = new HmacSha1();
        $this->consumer = new Consumer($consumerKey, $consumerSecret);
        if (!empty($oauthToken) && !empty($oauthTokenSecret)) {
            $this->token = new Token($oauthToken, $oauthTokenSecret);
        }
        if (empty($oauthToken) && !empty($oauthTokenSecret)) {
            $this->bearer = $oauthTokenSecret;
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param string $oauthToken
     * @param string $oauthTokenSecret
     */
    public function setOauthToken($oauthToken, $oauthTokenSecret)
    {
        $this->token = new Token($oauthToken, $oauthTokenSecret);
    }

    /**
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function getLastApiPath()
    {
        return $this->response->getApiPath();
    }

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getLastHttpCode()
    {
        return $this->response->getHttpCode();
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getLastXHeaders()
    {
        return $this->response->getXHeaders();
    }

    /**
     * @return array|object|null
     */
    public function getLastBody()
    {
        return $this->response->getBody();
    }

    /**
     * Resets the last response cache.
     */
    public function resetLastResponse()
    {
        $this->response = new Response();
    }
```

What seems to be wrong with my code? Is there a way to include the `Response` class into my file that I'm not aware of?

I'm also including a few screenshots to give an overview of my project's file structure:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to what you are trying to do. TwitterOAuth is much easier to install if you follow the [Composer install](https://twitteroauth.com/) instructions.

Comment: @abraham I completely agree with you. After spending an entire day trying to imitate tutorials available on the Internet with little success, I decide to go through your official instructions, and it hardly took me 15 minutes to get the access token necessary to interact with Twitter on behalf of the user. I'm not fond of official documentations, because usually the instructions are limited and difficult to understand for a novice programmer like myself.But you have done an amazing job with your documentation, and the instructions on `twitteroauth.com` were sufficient and easy to understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as you are using namespaces, add 'use Response' at the top, as for now your response class is not recognized

same way as you are using  Confing, just make sure linke to Response class will be recognized.

```
use Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth as Config;
use Abraham\TwitterOAuth\Response as Response;
```

or try to include it at the top:

```
require_once('your_path/Response.php');
```

Comment: I included this line of code in my file: `use twitteroauthm\src\Response;`. However, I'm encountering the following error: `atal error: Class 'twitteroauthm\src\Response' not found in /opt/lampp/htdocs/tmhOAuth-master/twitteroauth.php on line 110`

Comment: I suppose Response is you class, not coming with Twitter API,  right? Do you have it in the same namespace as Twitter? And are you using namespaces? Or maybe you just try to use 'require_once' statement, it is difficult to guess you app architecture

Comment: I'm not sure I understood your question. Could you kindly look into my file directory screenshots from my original post and tell me what needs to be done? The `Response` class is included in the `Response.php` file inside the `src` folder.

Comment: `require_once('twitteroauthm/src/Response.php');` gives me back the original error: `Fatal error: Class 'Response' not found.`

Comment: I'm sorry, didn't see it. What about to check in in 'autoload'  "twitteroauthm/autoload.php" resonse is included, and you try to include it there?

Comment: I checked the original class and the namespaces of Response is Abraham\TwitterOAuth, so try to add Abraham\TwitterOAuth\Response as Response at the top

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Do edit your answer so that I can accept it as the right one.

Comment: great, I'm happy that worked :) and thanks for accepting the answer